# Custom attributes for Flask WTForms

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask, wtforms

I develop website on Flask and AngularJS. I need to send a form whith AJAX using AngularJS but it requires a custom attribute for input field. For example I have a form in Jinja2 template:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name(placeholder="Name") }}
</form>
```

So how can I add an attribute from AngularJS lets say "ng-model" for my "name" field?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hrm; I don't think Jinja2 supports passing in a `**{...}` keyword splash, so `form.name(placeholder="Name", **{'ng-model': 'value'})` wouldn't work. I *think*.

Comment: I found a solution with WTForms Custom Widget. It has an example of adding 'class' attribute in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, a custom widget is what I'd use here, to work around the limitation in Jinja2.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Dashes are not permitted in Python identifiers, and only Python identifiers can be used as `keyword_argument=value` pairs in a call.

But you have several options to work around that here; you can pass in the `ng-` prefixed options in a `**kwargs` mapping, have the `Meta` class you use for the form translate `_` to `-` for `ng_` attributes, or use a custom widget to do the same translation.

### Pass in a **kwargs mapping

With `**kwargs` you can pass in arguments that are not Python identifiers, as long as they are strings. Use that to render your form fields:

```
{{ form.name(placeholder="Name", **{'ng-model': 'NameModel'}) }}
```

You can put the same information in the `render_kw` mapping on the field definition:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = StringField(u'Full Name', render_kw={'ng-model': 'NameModel'})
```

and it'll be used every time you render the field; `render_kw` is added to whatever arguments you pass in when you render, so:

```
{{ form.name(placeholder="Name") }}
```

would render both `placeholder` and `ng-model` attributes.

### Subclass Meta and use that in your form

As of WTForm 2.0, the [`Meta` class you attach to your form](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/meta.html) is actually asked to render fields with the [`Meta.render_field()` hook](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/meta.html#wtforms.meta.DefaultMeta.render_field):

```
import wtform.meta

class AngularJSMeta:
    def render_field(self, field, render_kw):
        ng_keys = [key for key in render_kw if key.startswith('ng_')]
        for key in ng_keys:
            render_kw['ng-' + key[3:]] = render_kw.pop(key)
        # WTForm dynamically constructs a Meta class from all Meta's on the
        # form MRO, so we can use super() here:
        return super(AngularJSMeta, self).render_field(field, render_kw)
```

Either use that directly on your form:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    Meta = AngularJSMeta

    name = StringField(u'Full Name')
```

or subclass the `Form` class:

```
class BaseAngularJSForm(Form):
    Meta = AngularJSMeta
```

and use that as the base for all your forms:

```
class MyForm(BaseAngularJSForm):
    name = StringField(u'Full Name')
```

and now you can use this is your template with:

```
{{ form.name(placeholder="Name", ng_model='NameModel') }}
```

### Subclass widgets

You could subclass the widget of your choice with:

```
class AngularJSMixin(object):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        for key in list(kwargs):
            if key.startswith('ng_'):
                kwargs['ng-' + key[3:]] = kwargs.pop(key)
        return super(AngularJSMixin, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)

class AngularJSTextInput(AngularJSMixin, TextInput):
    pass
```

This translates any keyword argument starting with `ng_` to a keyword argument starting with `ng-`, ensuring the right HTML attributes can be added. The `AngularJSMixin` can be used with any of the widget classes.

Use this as a `widget` attribute on your field:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = StringField(u'Full Name', widget=AngularJSTextInput())
```

and again you can use `ng_model` when renderig your template:

```
{{ form.name(placeholder="Name", ng_model='NameModel') }}
```

In all cases the attributes will be added as `placeholder="Name" ng-model="NameModel"` in the rendered HTML:

```
<input id="name" name="name" ng-model="NameModel" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: How do I call these in a jinja2 macro? Just `field.ng-model` somehow does not work for me.
I went with `{% if field.ng-model %} {{ field.ng-model }} {% endif %}`, but it does not work

Comment: @TobiasKolb: you are trying to access an attribute, and attribute names follow the same rules; `-` is the subtraction operator in Python code so can't be part of an identifier. Even so, `ng-model` is *not an attribute of the field*. If you used the `render_kw={...}` option to define the `ng-model` attribute value for your field, then you can use `field.render_kw['ng-model']` to access the value.

Comment: @TobiasKolb: (and apologies for only finding your comment now, 6 months after the fact, it must've slipped my attention at the time).

Answer (score 11):

```
{{ form.username(placeholder='your name', size=20, **{'ng-model':'hello', 'class':'hello'}) }}
```

I think is better

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks! If anyone is wondering, it prints all your other keys & values as well.

Comment: Still works lovely with Flask 1.x, am using this to add some custom attributes for client side validation.