# angularjs ng-model binding to wtforms csrf field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I need to add an ng-model field to a wtforms(>2.0) csrf field

this:

[Custom attributes for Flask WTForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440056/custom-attributes-for-flask-wtforms)

has helped with other fields, but I'm not sure how to get control over the csrf widget e.g. a field rendered using:

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

Any help? I think I could construct a field manually I think, but that seems too much work. I'd rather do:

```
{{ form.csrf_token(ng_model="model.csrfToken"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit ugly, but this is the only way I've been able to find:

```
{{ form.csrf_token(**{'ng-model':'csrfToken'}) }}
```

Unfortunately for us, Angular treats hidden fields specially and won't allow a two-way binding, so all that effort is for naught.  The hacky way I found around that is, in the controller, doing a lookup by ID.

```
var csrf_token = document.getElementById('csrf_token').value;
```